# How can I forward a page to the page number entered in a "jump to" form?

Tags: php, html, forms

I want to add a "jump to" form on one of my sites that has many pages so that my users can easily jump to any page.

Ideally, I want to do a simple `get` form (preferably, with no intermediary page) that will simply have a text field called `page`, and whatever page is entered, the form will immediately redirect to `http://mysite.com/mypage.php?p=[page]` (preferably, I would like the page number to be displayed in the URL of the redirected page).

What is the most straightforward way of doing that (**without Javascript**, only simple HTML/PHP) ?

Comment: if i understand this case as you are explaining , without javascript you cant do it .

Comment: @iskandarm:  So would I need to make the "action" point to an intermediary PHP page that gets the page value from the form and then does a header redirect to the appropriate URL ?

Comment: if you are on "mypage.php" and you want to redirect to mypage.php?p=[page] you can use <form action=<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?> >
and <input name="page" /> ... this is an example .... but if you have different pages and you need one page to distribute the clicks to different pages , so yes you need an intermediary php page .... if you can show us the code or a link to the page that you are working for maybe we can understand it better :) ... hope the comment was useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, this is a classic HTML form. No Javascript, no PHP needed:

```
<form action="mypage.php" method="get">
    Page: <input type="text" name="p" />
    <input type="submit" value="jump to page" />
</form>
```

You can insert this form on any page. When it's submitted, the browser will directly call `mypage.php?p=<inputValue>`.

Answer (score 0):

Without Javascript simple use links `<a href="http://mysite.com/mypage.php?p=3"> goto page 3</a>`

if you really want a form try

```
<form action ="http://mysite.com/mypage.php?p=3" method="GET">
<input type="submit" value=" GOTO page 3">
</form>

<form action ="http://mysite.com/mypage.php?p=4" method="GET">
<input type="submit" value=" GOTO page 4">
</form>

*laugh*
```

if you want a pull down menu or something you need JS to submit it in one click or you need to select and than click the "go" button (2 clicks)